# Conceptualizing a parse.com data structure for checkout lanes in a store

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, database-schema

I have a question concerning Parse.com and Swift. To make a long story short, I'm creating an app that allows installers of racking around cash registers to enter the details of checkout lanes into their phones, save it to Parse.com, and then have it be retrievable by the guys making the racks in the shop.

For the app, I was thinking of a basic flow like this: A) ask how many checkout lanes there are (x), B) populate a table view with x rows, C) each row represents a register that, when tapped, takes them to a detail view where they can enter details like lane and belt measurements, power sources, etc.

My question is how would I save the registers data to Parse, structurally speaking? Would I be creating a column that stores an array of complex register objects in the row for that specific store? Or would I create a store class, and then a registers class, and dump all those registers into the registers class and relate them, one to one, to the appropriate corresponding store?

I'm not having any issues with the actual saving of the data or the general programming, parse seems pretty straightforward, just conceptualizing the structure is giving me issues. Any help or links would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I think it should work:

**Store** class: holds information about all of the stores. Things like the number of registers, number of checkout lanes, location, etc. Stores get a randomly assigned identifier when they are set up.

**Register** class: holds information about all the possible registers. As you say, users can add them and define values. When created, assign parent store identifier. This should be relatively easy--just get the ID of the nearest store or ask the user what store they are in.

Then you can PFQuery all of the registers by knowing the store identifier, and create an array of all the registers.

Comment: I think you're right. This makes the most sense to me, and I'll try going this route first. One more thing: would it make sense to make a third class, Job Number, and have it be the parent of both of the store and register classes? (Since each job number will be unique and they may have multiple projects at, say, WalMart #210, eventually.)

Comment: Having the job class as a parent class sounds right.